# Firefox hang on jQuery based site after loading halfway when automating Selenium using Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, firefox, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a site that's jQuery based and I'm having trouble with getting the page to load completely before extracting the elements with Selenium.  The page has multiple modules, each of which is a different query.  I tried using the wait commands I found in the documentation, but it would usually hang the browser after one of the multiple queries load.

For reference, my OS is Windows 7, Firefox 30.0, Python 2.7 and Selenium 2.42.1

The commands and results I tried are as follows:

Explicit Wait: Browser hangs after loading the first query (Firefox Not Responding)

```
try:
   element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Expected Conditions: Browser hangs after loading the first query (Firefox Not Responding)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,path)))
```

Implicit Wait: Firefox hangs after loading the first query (Firefox Not Responding)

```
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
myDynamicElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath(path)
```

Custom Function: Page loads, but selenium starts scraping before the second query is loaded resulting in an error

```
def wait_for_condition(browser,c):
for x in range(1,10):
    print "Waiting for jquery: " + c
    x = browser.execute_script("return " + c)
if(x):
    return
time.sleep(1)

def main():
    wait_for_condition(browser,"jQuery.active == 0")

    #First element to be clicked on to scrape:
    path="//a[starts-with(@class, 'export db')]"
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
```

The error is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[starts-with(@class, \'export db\')]"}' ;
```

Catching this exception and running wait_for_condition again in the except block causes the browser to stop loading the rest of the queries and hang:

```
wait_for_condition(browser,"jQuery.active == 0")

try:
    path="//a[starts-with(@class, 'export db')]"
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    wait_for_condition(browser,"jQuery.active == 0")
    path="//a[starts-with(@class, 'export db')]"
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to solving the problems.
Thanks in advance,
Teresa

Comment: Is it a plain firefox profile or you added custom profile and plugins?

Comment: I added the following lines to the profile:    
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'D:\\TacoBell')
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'img/png')

Comment: Try removing those and see if it helps.

Comment: Sadly have the same results :(  Thanks for the suggestion though